# How can I add a row in a table by creating a row in other table in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I have a table named "**clien**t" that containd a **PK id(int)** with `auto_increment`, and I also have a tabble named "**profileImg**", with a **PK id(int)** with `auto_increment` and an **FK  idUser(int)** (`references to client.id ON DELETE CASCADE`).

I would like to add a row (**automatically**) in "profileImg" table when inserted a new row in the "client" table because.

In front hand, this means, that a client, when registers, has automatically a profile Image (a default one).

Is there a way to do this just with SQL?

Comment: What you are describing is an insert trigger on `clients`.  You should start by learning about those.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER add_profileImg_on_inser_client
AFTER INSERT ON client
FOR EACH ROW 
  INSERT INTO profileImg(idUser)
  VALUES (NEW.id);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I have solved this problem another way around, but not so secure I think, What I did was using only php, I registered a client with a $sql stmt and then I see the id (I was able to do this, because they also have to register with a UNIQUE nickname ```SELECT id FROM projeto WHERE nick=?``` ? = ```$nname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['nname']);```)with another stmt, and finally inserted the value (with a third stmt) on the profileImg, I did know that triggers could do that, but It was out of my knowledge, I will certainly study that after this university project is done.